# How to fix exception causing flutter app to fail at launch?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement google admob to add advertisement to my application, but when I do I start to get exceptions. Here is the current build error I am getting

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_admob...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+10\android\build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_admob'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.10.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+10\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

It says line 22 of the build.gradle file, which looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your need to Upgrade your Gradle Version to 5.1.1

in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

change

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

and in `android/build.gradle` 
under **buildscript --> dependencies**, change,

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1'

then try again.

Comment: When I do this, it says it can't locate the files when changed to 5.1.1. Is there anything further I have to do?